# How to create a new DateTime instance from a given W3C date string?

Tags: php, datetime, locale, date-format, date-formatting

I would like to create a DateTime Object, which should also set the correct timezone from the given W3C date string. An example of W3C date would be: `2014-03-12T09:30:04+0000`

I googled that a lot and couldn´t find a solution for it.

What I got till now is the following:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp(strtotime('2014-03-12T09:30:04+0000'));
var_dump($dt);
```

But I think this ignores the timezone, doesn´t it?

Comment: No, it does _not_ ignore the timezone, you just _think_ that because you are interpreting the debug output wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just this?

```
$dt = new DateTime('2014-03-12T09:30:04+0000');
print_r($dt);
```

My output:

```
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2014-03-12 09:30:04
    [timezone_type] => 1
    [timezone] => +00:00
)
```

So, it saves fine the timezone, but you probably are not interpreting fine the output; if you want to print it in YOUR local time, then you have to do some conversion.

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem by setting the timezone to `Europe/Berlin` on the `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$dt = new DateTime('2014-03-12T09:30:04+0400');
var_dump($dt);
```

last 4 numbers is for defining your timezone.

outputs

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(19) "2014-03-12 09:30:04"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(1)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(6) "+04:00"
}
```

in conclusion no it does not ignore timezone.